# Istanbul code coverage checking coverage of my spec files instead of source?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, code-coverage, istanbul

Just starting out with code coverage tools in general but I think I have everything set up correctly. However, Istanbul is generating a coverage report of my spec file rather than the source file?

when I run `jasmine-node repeatSpec.js --verbose`

I get:

```
 repeat Start
    repeats strings - 1 ms
  repeat Finish - 3 ms



Finished in 0.004 seconds
1 Tests, 0 Failures, 0 Skipped
```

which is correct, and if I fail my test on purpose it fails correctly as well.

However, when I run this istanbul command:

```
 istanbul cover  /d/Users/rkan/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/jasmine-node/bin/jasmine-node  repeatSpec.js
```

I get this respond, which is checking coverage based on my spec file.

```
=============================================================================
Writing coverage object [d:\playground\ue\node\Domain\WorkQueue\tests\coverage\coverage.json]
Writing coverage reports at [d:\playground\ue\node\Domain\WorkQueue\tests\coverage]
=============================================================================

=============================== Coverage summary ===============================
Statements   : 100% ( 5/5 )
Branches     : 100% ( 0/0 )
Functions    : 100% ( 2/2 )
Lines        : 100% ( 5/5 )
================================================================================
```

What did I do wrong?

Thanks!

nb - file directory is like this

```
|
|-lib/repeat.js
|
|-tests/repeatSpec.js
|
```

repeat.js

```
if (! String.prototype.repeat) {
        String.prototype.repeat = function (times) {
            return new Array(times+1).join(this);
        }
    }
if (x=68){
    x = 2;
}

if (x=200){
    x =5;
}
```

repeatSpec.js

```
require("../lib/repeat.js");

    describe("repeat", function() {
        it("repeats strings", function() {
            expect("abc".repeat(2)).toEqual("abcabc");
            expect("abc".repeat(0)).toEqual("");
        });
    });
```

Comment: I being very long time since this issue was raised. But, I am facing the same issue, coverage is generated for spec.js only and not .js files.
What was the solution you applied? It will be very helpfull. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to pass `mask: '*.spec.js'` option to your istanbul options configurations object.